# Nested for loop to identify locations in the same neighborhood

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested-loops, latitude-longitude

I have a pyspark dataframe with nearly half a million rows.

Sample dataframe:

```
df=
Location    Latitude    Longitude
loc_a       x1          y1
loc_b       x2          y2
loc_c       x3          y3
loc_d       x4          y4
loc_e       x5          y5
```

Now what I need to do is iterate over the dataframe to find locations in the same neighbourhood i.e., within a certain radius of say around 5 km.
The final dataframe needs to look like this:

```
distance= 
Source_location  Target_location    Distance
loc_a            loc_b              4.5
loc_a            loc_e              2.3
loc_b            loc_a              4.5
loc_b            loc_d              3.7
loc_c            loc_e              2.3
```

What I currently have is:

Since, 1 degree latitude ~ 111km

->0.07 degree ~ 7.7km

I use this logic to check the approximate distance between the two locations and then include only these locations in the resulting dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, FloatType, IntegerType
schema = StructType([
  StructField('Source_Location', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Source_Lat', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('Source_Long', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('Target_Location', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Target_Lat', FloatType(), True),
  StructField('Target_Long', FloatType(), True)
  ])

emptyRDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
result = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD,schema)

for i in df.collect():
  for j in df.collect():
    if (i!=j):
      source_lat, source_long, target_lat, target_long = i['Latitude'], i['Longitude'], j['Latitude'], j['Longitude']    
      if ((np.abs(source_lat - target_lat) <= 0.07) & (np.abs(source_long - target_long) <=0.07)):
        newRow = spark.createDataFrame([(i['Location'],i['Latitude'],i['Longitude'],j['Location'],j['Latitude'],j['Longitude'])])
        result = result.union(newRow)
```

Now that I have all the locations which are no further than ~7.7kms apart, I can use the latitude and longitude data of the two locations(Source and Target) to find the distance.

I then use the above result dataframe to compute the distance between the two locations.

Although it returns the desired results, it takes a very long time. Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Ps: The code I have I have pasted does not include the distance calculation part. It shows how I am trying to optimize the number of distance calculations that need to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to loop over such big data sets especially in spark (dont approach it with a for loop  like you would in python). It will take too long. As per your code, you are reading a single record at a time which will not allow spark to run in parallel. Spark code should be design without for and while loop if you have large data set.

I just refactored your code for the solution you are asking. I did not add any additional information how to calulate the distance since this is not the question. You could do something like below:

- Create a boolean new column "within_5_km"
- filter the dataframe if its True (hence within 5km)
- drop the column
- then you have your dataframe in which you can calculate the distiance

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import abs, col, lit, when

#start spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

#create example df
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.11),
        (2.1, 4.4, 6.6, 9.8),
    ],
    ['Source_Lat', 'Source_Long', 'Target_Lat', 'Target_Long']  # add your column names here
)

# find values within 0.07 - i guess you meant 7km? anyway this is adjustable
df = df.withColumn("within_7km", when(
    (abs(col("Source_Lat")-col("Target_Lat")) < 0.07) & 
    (abs(col("Source_Long")-col("Target_Long")) < 0.07), 
    lit(True)).otherwise(False)
)

#filter the dataframe to only have the values within the neighbourhood and then drop the column you created
result = df.filter(col("within_5km")==True).drop("within_7km")

)
```

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. I've made edits. What I have is the dataframe 'df' which is unique on the column 'Location'. From this dataframe I need to generate the 'distance' dataframe. For instance: I want a list of all locations (target location) within a 5km radius to location a (source location). 
Hope this makes my question more clear.